# Netty 3.9 setTrafficClass() method does appear to work

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 3.9.5 and have used the code listed on this page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_%28software%29#Netty_TCP_Example to build a simple server program and client program. Both of my machines are Windows 7 and I am using JDK 1.8.   The programs work fine.

My current project requires me to set the DSCP code for the packet that I am sending from the client to the server.  Here is the relevant code I added to the Netty Client example.

```
    Channel comLink = connection.getChannel();

    /* Hopefully this will set the traffic class in the channel. */

    SocketChannelConfig cfg = (NioSocketChannelConfig) comLink.getConfig();
    cfg.setTrafficClass(0x08);
//  cfg.setOption("trafficClass", 8);
    System.out.println("The traffic class is " + cfg.getTrafficClass());
```

It does not matter if I use setTrafficClass or setOption.  The value always printed is 0.  Additionally Wireshark on both the client and the server show 0.

Is there something else I need to do?  My ultimate goal is to get the programs to run under Windows and Ubuntu.  I have seen Windows articles about problems with setTrafficClass if java.net.Socket is used, but I do not know if this is related in any way.

I am assuming there is something I do not understand and any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Phil

Comment: Does setting the option on bootstrap (both parent and child) work for you ?

Comment: Adding to the bootstrap did not work.  What worked was leaving my code as I entered and adding the vm property -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: Seems a JDK bug, not Netty: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7169676

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but according to Java doc of Socket class:

> As RFC 1122 section 4.2.4.2 indicates, a compliant TCP implementation
>   should, but is not required to, let application change the TOS field
>   during the lifetime of a connection. So whether the type-of-service
>   field can be changed after the TCP connection has been established
>   depends on the implementation in the underlying platform. Applications
>   should not assume that they can change the TOS field after the
>   connection.

So I imagine that you should put this before the channel is created, so in the BootStrap, you might need to do something as:

```
ClientBootstrap bootstrap = ...
bootstrap.setOption("trafficClass", 0x08);
```

and/or

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = ...
boostrap.setOption("trafficClass", 0x08);//not sure for this one but cost nothing
bootstrap.setOption("child.trafficClass", 0x08);
```

Setting the values once connected is not apparently guaranteed.
You may try...